# Why does blender info log open wherever I click? I can't find anything about this

Tags: modeling, animation

[image]I use blender for 3D animation, It started a month ago when wherever I clicked, Blender Info Log would open. Does anyone know a way to fix this? I can't find anything about this anywhere.

Comment: Hello. Please provide a little more information. A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: How? I'm a bit new.

Comment: [Edit the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and then click on the [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoc0p.png) to add a picture

Comment: I haven't touched blender in a while because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the solution to your problem go to edit>preferences

[image]

then go to the three lines located on the bottom of your preferences tab

[image]

Then select load factory settings
and now when you left click the info log wont appear hopefully

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: your welcome! happy to help

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have mixed up your keymap. Could you please check if the System Console menu item in the Window menu has a hotkey assigned? If so, right click at it, and choose Remove Shortcut from the upcoming menu.

[image]